# How to catch NotFoundException with ControllerAdvice in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception, controller-advice

I'm working at a Spring Boot project and I want to handle the exceptions for the REST API using `@ControllerAdvice`. And I want to handle the case when the endpoint is not spelled correctly. For example the endpoint should be `http://localhost:8080/website` and the client app makes a mistake and call the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/websit` and right now I get that response in the browser:

Here is the response that I get now:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Nov 19 15:31:33 EET 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I want to know if I can handle it with `@ControllerAdvice` and I don't know what kind of `NotFoundException` to catch in the `ControllerAdvice` class.

ControllerAdvice class:

```
import com.ds.ecommerce.exception.PriceNotFoundException;
import javassist.NotFoundException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationException;

@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class PricesGlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ErrorDTO handleException(Exception exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return ErrorDTO.builder()
                .code(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase())
                .message("Unexpected error!")
                .build();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ValidationException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ErrorDTO handleException(ValidationException validationException) {
        String exceptionMessage = validationException.getMessage();
        log.error(exceptionMessage, validationException);
        return ErrorDTO.builder()
                .code(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase())
                .message(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {PriceNotFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorDTO handleException(PriceNotFoundException priceNotFoundException) {
        String exceptionMessage = priceNotFoundException.getMessage();
        log.error(exceptionMessage, priceNotFoundException);
        return ErrorDTO.builder()
                .code(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase())
                .message(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NotFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorDTO handleException(NotFoundException notFoundException) {
        String exceptionMessage = notFoundException.getMessage();
        log.error(exceptionMessage, notFoundException);
        return ErrorDTO.builder()
                .code(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase())
                .message(exceptionMessage)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I think I'm not using the correct `NotFoundException` class to catch it.
Thank you!

Comment: The question is not spelled correctly.

Comment: If it is a controller level exception and not from filters, you can handle it in controller advice, if you are getting any error on doing it, can you please specify it?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I want to handle the case when the URL is not spelled correctly, for example the endpoint should be /website, and the client app make a request to /websit

Comment: @elvis I think it redirects to /error page and their you can override the response. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControllerAdvice handles only exceptions that originate from within some end-point method and are not cought. If your URL is misspelled, than obviously your code did not yet enter any of the end-points and thus the exception will not be handled by ControllerAdvice.